# Is there any hotkey to input A1 as $A$1 in Google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

For instance,

I have a finance sheet. And I would calculate the currency rate via this function:

```
GOOGLEFINANCE("AUDUSD")
```

Then, I put the result in `A1`.

And then, I need to convert some of my cells to the target currency by `*$A1$1`. After I ket the `*` key, I can use mouse to select the cell `A1`. And then, I have to enter the cell, putting my caret to the place and add two `$` signs.

Inputing `$` is really annoying. Is there any hotkey to do this?

Comment: Please read [Keyboard shortcuts for Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cpc-shortcuts) (P.S. On Windows the hotkey is F4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `F4` key will do this. See [Keyboard shortcuts for Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110)